# Laravel automated invoice reminder email on due date, after 3days, after a week from different users to different clients

Tags: laravel, email, reminders

#### I am implementing a invoice API system for that I have to implement an automated reminder email on due date, after 3days, after 7days (it is like a API so the email has to be send from login user email to the selected customer)

For this system so far I implemented a checkbox selection which will store the login user, selected customer, due date, day selection for reminder stored the data in database). I have issues in sending emails from different users, adding condition to send email from the due date

console->commands->SendReminderemail.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
Use App\Reminder;
use App\Donor;
use App\Mail\ReminderEmailDigest;
Use Mail;

class SendReminderEmails extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'reminder:emails';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Invoice Reminder Emails';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //

        $pending_Reminders = Reminder::where('status',0)->get();
        
        $data = [];

        foreach ($pending_Reminders as $reminder){
            $data[$reminder->donor_id][] = $reminder->toArray();        
        }

        foreach($data as $donor_id => $pending_Reminders){
            $this->sendEmailToUser($donor_id, $pending_Reminders);
        }
        // dd($data);
    }

    private function sendEmailToUser($donor_id, $pending_Reminders){

        $user = Donor::find($donor_id);

        Mail::to($user)->send(new ReminderEmailDigest($pending_Reminders));

        // dd($user);
    }

}
```

App->mail->ReminderEmailDigest

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ReminderEmailDigest extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private $pending_Reminders;

    public function __construct($pending_Reminders)
    {
        $this->reminders = $pending_Reminders;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.reminder-digest')
        ->with('pending_Reminders', $this->reminder);
    }
}
```

App->console->kernal

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use App\Console\Commands\SendReminderEmails;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */


    protected $commands = [
        SendReminderEmails::class,
    ];
    
    
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('reminder:emails')->everyMinute();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }

    
}
```

#### Now only the email working when I enter the reminder:emails command in console

How can i automate the mail?? any related suggestions??

Comment: Are you asking how to run `reminder:emails` as a cron job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a note on how you could clean up your code.

```
    $pending_Reminders = Reminder::where('status',0)
        ->get()
        ->groupBy('donor_id')
        ->each(function($reminders, $donor_id) {
            $user = Donor::find($donor_id);
            Mail::to($user)->send(new ReminderEmailDigest($reminders->toArray()));
        });
```

To set the artisan command to run daily,

app/Console/Kernel.php

```
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('reminder:emails')->daily();
    }
```

To get that to run `sudo crontab -e`

```
* * * * * cd path/to/project && /usr/local/bin/php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but to activate the cron job I have to do some configurations in the hosting provider cron jobs right!!  (do I need to run the 'sudo crontab -e' command ??)

Comment: Depends on your server setup :) if you are using cpanel you can do it there, If you are using a vps and just SSH the command i linked works, If you are working on MAC in development the command i linked works (for development) either way the command is what you will also put in the cpanel box (while updating the project path and php binary path)

Comment: okay I'm using cpanel I can configure it in the server, is there any way to send email from logged user email(depend on Auth), that I can use in the mail sending function in console/commands/SendReminderemail.php ??

Comment: A console command has no idea of who is auth, are you wanting it to send form the doners owner? e.g, does `Doner` belong to a user. if so just set it to send from them.

Comment: Not a console command, in the above mention code I am sending mail to donors ( now all the email from same email address for example- predefined address in config/Mail but can I change it send from logged in user email address )

Comment: I understand what you are after however like I said, How is this command to be ran by the logged in user. It cant. If the donor has a relation to an owner you can set it to send from them. However without giving the logged in user a button to press that will send emails this is not possible. `->from($user->email, $user->name)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to schedule your command.
For that, check how to [register your command](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands) to schedular and how to set up [cron job](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler) for schedular to run.

More specifically, you can do something like this:

```
$schedule->command('reminder:emails')->daily();
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will check in the documentation (is there any way to send mail from logged user email, that i can use in the mail sending function in console->commands->SendReminderemail.php)